# How to ignore some errors with Sentry (not to send them)?

Tags: python, django, sentry

I have a project based on django (3.2.10) and sentry-sdk (1.16.0)
There is my sentry-init file:

```
from os import getenv


SENTRY_URL = getenv('SENTRY_URL')

if SENTRY_URL:
    from sentry_sdk import init
    from sentry_sdk.integrations.django import DjangoIntegration
    from sentry_sdk.integrations.redis import RedisIntegration
    from sentry_sdk.integrations.celery import CeleryIntegration

    init(
        dsn=SENTRY_URL,
        integrations=[DjangoIntegration(), RedisIntegration(), CeleryIntegration()],
        traces_sample_rate=1.0,
        send_default_pii=True,
        debug=True,
    )
```

I have a CustomError inherited from Exception

Every time I raise the CustomError sentry-sdk sends it to the dsn-url.

I want to ignore some class of error or something like this.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a function that filters the errors to be sent:

```py
from os import getenv


SENTRY_URL = getenv('SENTRY_URL')

if SENTRY_URL:
    from sentry_sdk import init
    from sentry_sdk.integrations.django import DjangoIntegration
    from sentry_sdk.integrations.redis import RedisIntegration
    from sentry_sdk.integrations.celery import CeleryIntegration
  
    def before_send(event, hint):
       if 'exc_info' in hint:
          exc_type, exc_value, tb = hint['exc_info']
          if isinstance(exc_value, CustomError):  # Replace CustomError with your custom error 
             return None
       return event

    init(
        dsn=SENTRY_URL,
        integrations=[DjangoIntegration(), RedisIntegration(), CeleryIntegration()],
        traces_sample_rate=1.0,
        send_default_pii=True,
        debug=True,
        before_send=before_send
    )
```

You can find more info in the [documentation](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/python/guides/django/configuration/filtering/).